# Criar template Bootstrap para ser usado em todas as páginas JSP de sua app Java, implementando somente o "content/conteúdo"

Tags: java, jsp, template, bootstrap

Bom dia,

Pessoal, "sei que é mais um assunto do mesmo", mas alguém poderia me ajudar com essa dúvida.

Estou acostumado a fazer templates com facelets, então eu gero um arquivo xhtml e anoto dentro do mesmo, onde vai ser o Header, o Content e o Footer. Dessa forma, nas demais páginas, eu importo o template através de uma tag.

Minha dúvida é:

Como eu posso fazer algo semelhante, mas utilizando o Bootstrap, eu preciso gerar uma página principal, onde terá a estrutura do template, e nas demais páginas do projeto, eu vou apenas implementar o contéudo, sem necessidade de re-escrever todo o código HTML.

Obs:
Estou pesquisando também na web mas tive muitas dúvidas, por isso escrevi aqui.

Obrigado.

Comment: Everton, o site funciona diferente de um fórum. Se você achou uma resposta, você pode responder a pergunta(como já fez) e depois marcá-la como aceita, clicando no `V` a esquerda da resposta. Isso é que valida uma pergunta como "solucionada" aqui no SOpt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode também usar taglibs, basta adicionar na pasta WEB-INF uma pasta para o conteúdo que você quer criar e a ai ir adicionando pequenos arquivos com as tags em si exemplo:

- Criar a pasta WEB-INF/tags:
- Dentro dela cria um arquivo chamado header.tag

E nele adicionar o código que se pretende utilizar, exemplo:

```
<%@ attribute name="urlImage" required="true"%>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
           <img alt="Brand" src="${urlImage}">
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

E em sua jsp usa-la da seguinte maneira:

```
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="tag"%>
<tag:header urlImage="url/da/imagem"/>
```

E para os demais é o mesmo processo.

Comment: Legal Nelson, valeu, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma:

1: Os trechos que não iriam mudar, por exemplo o Menu, criei um arquivo chamado menu.jsp, e deixei somente o código do menu no arquivo.

Na página home.jsp, eu importei a página menu.jsp.

menu.jsp:  (Gerar um arquivo em branco e apenas escrever o código do seu menu), pois será atribuído ao home.jsp.

home.jsp: (Aqui sim, deverá ter o cabeçalho completo da uma JSP)

Dentro da tag body:

```
jsp:include page="template/menu.jsp"
```